# Error managment in ControllerAdvice lead to duplication in URI and 404

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a simple rest controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class OrderController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/orders2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public OrderDto createOrder2(@RequestBody OrderDto order) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Bouh!");
    }
}
```

And I want to manage exceptions globally. From what I read it can be done with something like :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ErrorDto handleConflict(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) throws Exception {
        ErrorDto o = new ErrorDto ();
        o.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return o;
    }
}
```

But when I make a post on my request, I get the following error :

```
26/10/2016 17:26:08.187 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - 
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/duorest/api/v1/api/v1/orders2] 
in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'
```

I don't know why the uri change to /duorest/**api/v1/api/v1**/orders2

Some facts :

- I checked in debug, my code is executed
- If I move the method in the rest controller, I get no error and what I expect (my ErrorDto object)
- Spring framework version 4.3.3.RELEASE
- Spring-data-rest-webmvc version 2.5.4.RELEASE

Anybody already had this problem ? Or any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it resolved? if not please try to execute with `@ResponseBody` is missing on the `handleConflict` method.

Comment: I knew it was something minor, that was it, a missing annotation !

Comment: Of course always something minor we miss most of the times :). Good my answer helped you